Matplotlib pgf export: supylabel misaligned
I am trying to add a supylabel to two subplots in matplotlib and export the result as a .pgf. However, the supylabel is clearly not centered.
This is the python code:
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(
    2,
    1,
    figsize=(3, 3),
    squeeze=True,
    sharex=True,
    sharey=True,
    layout="constrained"
)

xy = numpy.linspace(-80, 70)
z = numpy.zeros((len(xy), len(xy)))

supylabel_text = fig.supylabel("Super-y axis label")

for i in range(2):
    ax: pyplot.Axes = axes[i]
    im = ax.pcolormesh(
        xy, xy, z, shading="gouraud", rasterized=True
    )
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    # Remove all ticks and labels, see comment.
    # ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    # ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

fig.savefig("test_supy.pgf")
fig.savefig("test_supy.pgf.pdf")

This is the figure as rendered inside a latex document:

Clearly, the supylabel hangs too low. Interestingly, in the pdf which is also exported from the code above, it is placed correctly:

This is the generated PGF:
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\begin{pgfpicture}%
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{3.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{3.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{3.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.980000in}{1.680000in}%
\pgftext[left,bottom]{\includegraphics[interpolate=true,width=1.280000in,height=1.280000in]{test_supy-img0.png}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.239357in}{1.681793in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.664869in}{1.681793in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.090381in}{1.681793in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{1.937100in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.602071in, y=1.884339in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}\ensuremath{-}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{2.362613in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.798462in, y=2.309851in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}0}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{2.788125in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.710096in, y=2.735364in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.681793in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{2.958330in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{1.000000,1.000000,1.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.000000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{0.000000}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathclose%
\pgfusepath{fill}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.980000in}{0.270000in}%
\pgftext[left,bottom]{\includegraphics[interpolate=true,width=1.280000in,height=1.280000in]{test_supy-img1.png}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.239357in}{0.273305in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=1.239357in,y=0.176083in,,top]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}\ensuremath{-}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{1.664869in}{0.273305in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=1.664869in,y=0.176083in,,top]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}0}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.000000in}{-0.048611in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{2.090381in}{0.273305in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=2.090381in,y=0.176083in,,top]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{0.528612in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.602071in, y=0.475851in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}\ensuremath{-}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{0.954125in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.798462in, y=0.901363in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}0}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetbuttcap%
\pgfsetroundjoin%
\definecolor{currentfill}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{currentfill}%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfsys@defobject{currentmarker}{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-0.000000in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-0.048611in}{0.000000in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}%
}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsys@transformshift{0.984049in}{1.379637in}%
\pgfsys@useobject{currentmarker}{}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.710096in, y=1.326875in, left, base]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}50}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{0.273305in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\pgfsetrectcap%
\pgfsetmiterjoin%
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.803000pt}%
\definecolor{currentstroke}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{currentstroke}%
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.984049in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{2.260586in}{1.549842in}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\begin{pgfscope}%
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}%
\pgfsetstrokecolor{textcolor}%
\pgfsetfillcolor{textcolor}%
\pgftext[x=0.168298in, y=0.761800in, left, base,rotate=90.000000]{\color{textcolor}{\sffamily\fontsize{12.000000}{14.400000}\selectfont\catcode`\^=\active\def^{\ifmmode\sp\else\^{}\fi}\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}Super-y axis label}}%
\end{pgfscope}%
\end{pgfpicture}%
\makeatother%
\endgroup%

After removing all ticks and labels, the supylabel is still misaligned:


Are you sure it's misaligned and not that it appears that way because of the x-ticks on the bottom plot? It might be centered once you account for those.

The label is still not centered when I remove all ticks and labels as shown in the code now.

It looks like the "S" is in the same place for pgf and pdf, but the font size is smaller.  I suggest opening a bug report in the Matplotlib GitHub repo.

All your fonts are smaller.  How are you including the pgf in your latex document?

@JodyKlymak Yes, but the font should be the same since the header is the same for matplotlib and the rendered picture I've shown. Also, the PGF should select the correct font. Generally, I don't see why the PGF and the PDF are not identical.

How are you including the pdf in your latex document?

@JodyKlymak No, the PDF I have shown is the standalone PDF exported from the plot script with fig.savefig("test_supy.pgf.pdf").

Typo/autocorrect: how are you saving the pgf?
